# Argument list too long while stack size id unlimited and command size is about 300 kbyte

Tags: c++, linux, qt, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to compile Unreal engine under Sabayon Linux using Qt creator and I always get [**execv: Argument list too long**](http://pastebin.com/5436wAvk) error.

I've already googled this problem and I've tried to increase stack size by editing **/etc/security/limits.conf** file. I event set it to unlimited so now **getconf ARG_MAX** output is **16777216**. The command size qt creator is trying to exec is about 300 kbytes.

Please help me to find out what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Why would stack size have anything to do with this?

Comment: The error message is right, that's a heck of a argument list. Did you try to build it from command line, with the steps that are probably documented somewhere in the unreal docs? I don't see any advantage by trying to do it in qtcreator.

Comment: In Linux the arguments lists size is 1/4 of the stack size that is why I changed it.

Comment: I've tried to compile it like it was described in documentation, it worked. I just want to make whole coding, compiling and debugging in qt creator.

Comment: I'm sorry for wasting your time, it seems like I'm too stupid. I've found the way to fix this, I'll write it in answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found the way to fix this. As  [Frank Osterfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/299399/frank-osterfeld) said, you better compile it like it is described in [documentation](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Building_On_Linux). And if you want to use Qt creator in your projects, just follow [this article](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Using_QtCreator_With_UnrealEngine4).